# Confluent Schema Registry unable to connect to Kafka container

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to run a Kafka service with Zookeper, Kafdrop and Schema Registry, I made it work by installing Kafka, Zookeper and Kadrop in a container and then installing Confluent Schema Registry in another (with its own Kafka, Zookeeper, Ksql Server and Rest Proxy), however trying to make kafdrop read the schema registry is not working, so now I want to install exclusively just one container with Kafka, Zookeeper, Kafdrop and Schema Registry, and even though everything is installed successfully, the Schema Registry is restarting every 10 seconds or so, and I cannot reach out the service (localhost:8085) to add my schema, so I'm wondering if it's even possible to run the Confluent Schema Registry outside the Confluent suite of services, here it is my YAML file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
      - KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=schemaregistry:8085
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=zookeeper
   
  schemaregistry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: "zookeeper:2181"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schemaregistry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8085"
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:29092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_CONNECT: schemaregistry:8085
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". If you'd provided the logs for the container crashing, you'd get a better answer. Besides that, Confluent provides an all-in-one Compose file in github that works fine, all you needed to do was add kafdrop to it

Answer (score 2):

So it turned out that the Schema Registry couldn't connect because Kafka was not using 'PLAINTEXT' as the internal broker listener name, here is the YAML version working with the Kafdrop also working when deserializing the message to AVRO:

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=schemaregistry:8085

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=zookeeper
   
  schemaregistry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: "zookeeper:2181"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schemaregistry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8085"
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:29092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_CONNECT: http://schemaregistry:8085
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
```

Comment: I was having a ton of trouble getting schema registry to connect to Wurstmeister kafka. This example worked wonders. Thank you!!!

Note: you can use the default 8081 port for schema registry and it will work fine as well

Also personally I would stick to using the colon style (or the = style) for environment variables but it doesn't make a different in how the program runs.
Thanks again for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Your both YAML are not correct
You have in zookeeper:
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME

And in schema registry you give zookeeper port 2181 in kafkastore....

Comment: So my schema registry should be pointing to Kafka instead of zookeeper?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html